# Reading a string and splitting it

Tags: javascript, string

I am looking to take an HTML text string split it in half and compare the two to see if they equal each other. The string is like:

```
0:02 / 0:33
```

So as you can see, I'm looking for a way to split the string. And grab the two values that are divided by the `/`. And if they equal each other, then have the script do its job.

Comment: Are you using Java or JavaScript?

Comment: I'm currently using javascript and as the title says I'm using grease monkey to manipulate pages. *rhetorical*

Comment: As the tags said, you listed Java, which is a very different technology from JavaScript.  Well you have a working answer below, but maybe next time you can tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Google "javascript split string".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `split` the string, trim the two parts and compare them quite easily:

```js
function test( str ) {
    var substrs = str.split('/').map(function(substr) {
        return substr.trim();
    });
    if ( substrs[0] == substrs[1] )
        document.write('same');
    else
        document.write('not same');
}

test("0:01 / 0:30");
document.write('<br />');
test("0:30 / 0:30");
```

Comment: Thanks, for the help! I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, make sure when you find an answer solves your problem, you mark it as accepted, so others searching for a similar problem know what helped in your case.